# shear stress at particular point in beam

Tags: structural-engineering

In [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxBsb.png), I suspect the selected A' (area) is wrong... From [the notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRnF0.png), A' is the "portion of the member's cross sectional area above the section where t is measured". But, in the example, we could see that the selected area is located to the right of the point where shear stress is calculated. Are the notes wrong?

***I believe the selected A' should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfHQe.png)*** (refer to green shaded part). Am I right?

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to discuss with the instructor for your course? Homework checking questions are usually not well received here as they provide little lasting value to the community.

Comment: I just  wanna  verify  my  concept ,  BTW ,  this  is   not  homework...  This  is  just  notes

Comment: Anyone  can  help ?

Comment: I said so because A is the area above or below the member's cross sectional area

Comment: Why this topic was put on hold ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area A' is the excluded area for the cut under consideration. To get the shear stress at a location you "cut" the section there, and look at the area beyond the cut.

For the shear stress in the web at the top of the web, the whole of the flange is excluded (your third picture). For the shear stress in the flange adjacent to the web, only the part of the flange beyond that cut is excluded (your first picture).

Comment: why you said that 

The area A' is the excluded area for the part under consideration.. Shouldnt be A' =  area for the part under consideration ????

Comment: @kelvinmacks - Hmm, maybe that wasn't the clearest. Edited to say "The area A' is the excluded area for the **cut** under consideration"

Comment: Can  you  explain  further ?  I am  still  not  clear....

Comment: If you want the shear stress in the web, you need to make a "cut" in the web, this "cut" splits the section into two separate areas: the "excluded area" (which is the flange), and the rest of the section. If you want the shear stress in the flange, you need to make a "cut" in the flange. If you made a horizontal cut, you would get the vertical stress; if you make a vertical cut, you get the horizontal shear stress. The question asks for horizontal shear stress, so you need a vertical cut, which cuts of one leg of the flange. I hope that's clearer?

Comment: Why  horizontal  stress,  we  would  need  vertical  cut ?

Comment: Because you want the stress across the cut. If you want vertical stress, then it travels across a horizontal plane; if you want horizontal stress, then it travels across a vertical plane.

Comment: why we need to cut the beam vertically when we are calculating for horizontal shear stress and vice versa?

Comment: @kelvinmacks - How is that any different to your previous comment? How does my previous comment not answer that?

Comment: why vertical stress, then it travels across a horizontal plane; if you want horizontal stress, then it travels across a vertical plan??

Comment: @kelvinmacks - I'm afraid I don't know how else to explain it.

Comment: can you try your best to explain ?

Comment: What do you think I've been doing for the past 5 comments?!?!

Comment: When i cut the beam vertically , the portion of the beam that has been cut off can travel vertically and also horizontally , that's why i am confused

Comment: here's what i found http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/stress-strain-d_950.html  , when the object is sheared , it move horizontally , so it's horizontal shear stress , right ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/RqcWz do you mean this ? if we cut the flange vertically , then the shear stress acting is horizontal shear stress that prevent the members to slide over from each other ?

Comment: See [this image on shear flow](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=shear+flow&biw=825&bih=839&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwibkPCqupnQAhVFBSwKHdUhATEQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.95#imgrc=WVlFihRfHaYUKM%3A). Vertical shear causes horizontal shear flow in the flanges of an I section. And this is where my knowledge ends I'm afraid, I can't remember from my uni course how or why it does that.